# batファイルでツイートをするときのテキストの改行方法

Tags: python, windows, cmd

pythonのtweepyでスケジュールツイートをすることにして、pyファイルを呼び出して、そこにテキスト入力できるように、sys.argvを使って以下のバッチファイルを作りました。

```
set /p Tweet="Tweet:"
set /p Time="Time:" 
Scheduler_Tweet.py %Tweet% %Time%
```

一行だけをツイートするときにはこれで問題なく動くのですが、複数行をツイートしたいときに「\n」で改行させようとしたらそのまま文字としてツイートされてしまいました。

なにか改行を反映させる方法がありましたらお教えください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

ちなみにScheduler_Tweet.pyの中は、

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CK, CS) 
auth.set_access_token(AT, AS) 
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def job():  
 api.update_status(status=(sys.argv[1]))

def main():     
 schedule.every().day.at((sys.argv[2])).do(job)


 while True:        
  schedule.run_pending()        
  time.sleep(1)

main()
```

です。

Comment: `/n`ではなく`\n`では？ `Scheduler_Tweet.py`の内容を提示した方が良いでしょう。全部では無くてもパラメータをツイートするテキストに組み立てる部分を抜き出せば良いでしょうし、それで自分自身でも詳細な動作状況を確認出来るのでは？

Comment: 失礼いたしました。\nでした。それでも改行はされません。
コマンドプロンプトだと\nは反映されないのかなと思うのですが、
何か策があればご教示くださいませ。

Scheduler_Tweet.pyの中は以下のようになっております。


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CK, CS)
auth.set_access_token(AT, AS)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def job():
 api.update_status(status=(sys.argv[1]))

def main():
 schedule.every().day.at((sys.argv[2])).do(job)


 while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)

main()

Comment: `status=(sys.argv[1])`を`status=(sys.argv[1].replace("\\n","\n"))`に書き換えると結果は変わりますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！こちらに置き換えたところ「\n」の入力で改行できました！
どういう理屈なのかはこれから調べて学んでいきたいと思います！
本当にありがとうございました！！

Answer (score 0):

例えばこんな最小のスクリプトを作って`Scheduler_Tweet.py`の代わりにバッチファイルに指定して実行してみれば何が渡されてくるか分かるでしょう。
入力された`\n`がそのまま表示されますね。

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
```

そしてこの辺の記事が対策になると考えられます。
[Pythonでエスケープされた文字列を戻す](https://www.xn--ebkc7kqd.com/entry/python-unescape)
[pythonでescapeされた（？）文字列をunescape（？）する方法のメモ](https://pod.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/08/30/210044)
[How to un-escape a backslash-escaped string? の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57192592/9014308)

ただし、単純に適用するとASCII範囲外(全角文字や半角カナ)の文字が化けてしまうので、`.encode()`には上記英語版記事の回答を適用します。

上記スクリプトに適用すれば以下のようになるでしょう。

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1].encode('latin1', errors='backslashreplace').decode('unicode-escape'))
print(sys.argv[2].encode('latin1', errors='backslashreplace').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

`Scheduler_Tweet.py`スクリプトのコマンドラインパラメータ文字列を取り出す該当部分を上記のようにして試してみてください。

参考：
[str.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)
[bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)
[標準エンコーディング](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)
[テキストエンコーディング](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)

Comment: ありがとうございます！こちらでも無事に「\n」で改行することができました！
ずっと探していたのですが、わからずだったので、これから置換など調べて学んでいきたいと思います！
本当にありがとうございました！！

Answer (score 0):

コマンドプロンプトの引数として`\n`を渡した場合、改行コードの`\n`ではなく文字列の「\n(pythonソースコードの`"\\n"`または`r"\n"`表記)」が渡されます。
[`tweepy.API.update_status`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.update_status)に改行コードを送ることで改行を反映することができます。

**sample.py**

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[1].replace("\\n","\n"))
```

上記のsample.pyに対して

> python .\sample.py ほげ\nふが
> を実行した結果は下記になります。

```
ほげ\nふが
ほげ
ふが
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！どういう仕組みなのかようやくわかりました。
これで「\n」で改行をすることができます。
本当にありがとうございました！！